# GCCJIT, get the size of a type

Tags: c, gcc, libgccjit

Given a gcc_jit_type pointer is there any way to get its size?  I have been looking over the documentation and I can't really find an example of something like the sizeof operator.  I would like to write a kind of generic data structure which is given a gcc_jit_type and compiles itself from that.  Kind of hard to do if I don't know the size of the type.

Comment: The low-volume  `jit@gcc.gnu.org` mailing list is probably a better place to ask such a question

Comment: And then you can self-answer here :)

Comment: Then place as a first field the size of the object/type.

Comment: "Given a gcc_jit_type pointer is there any way to get its size? " Curious, why does `sizeof(gcc_jit_type)` not give you the size of the pointer?

Comment: Yeah that does give me the size of the pointer in my c program.  What I am talking about is getting the size of the type in the program I am JIT compiling.

Comment: libgccjit author unfortunately has put "sizeof" into the "probably not needed" category in his TODO list: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/jit/TODO.rst#probably-not-needed. Although, this probably refers to a compile-time sizeof (which would return an integer rather than gcc_jit_rvalue*) - it is trickier to implement.

Comment: Well I managed to hack this one in my self answer bellow.  I think it is kind of important since one of the main uses I see for a JIT is where types or structures are not know at compile time. It would also be nice if there were functions to access other meta information about the types.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to hack together a solution but I feel like it was way harder than it should have been.  There definitely should something like `gcc_jit_type_sizeof(...)` function added to the api in my opinion.

I realized that in C code `sizeof(T) = (size_t)(1 + (T*)0)` so I tried to implement this with gccjit.  In doing do I realized there is no real way to increment a pointer given the api.  I tried to use the addition binary opp but this gave me an error since both operands need to be of the same type.  Adding an int to a pointer is invalid in gccjit.  I tried assigning one pointer to zero and another to one and adding those but that gave a strange result.  I guess this makes sense since `(int*)0 + (int*)1` is a compile error in C.

The next thing I tried was the this C equivalent `(size_t)&((T*)0)[1] - (size_t)((T*)0)` which also failed to compile becase in gccjit you can't cast a pointer type to an int either.  I finally got it to work by changing it to `(char*)&((T*)0)[1] - (char*)((T*)0)` since you can cast a pointer to another pointer type.

```
gcc_jit_rvalue* jit_sizeof(gcc_jit_context* ctx, gcc_jit_type* t)
{   
    const void* NULL_PTR = 0;

    gcc_jit_type* t_ptr_type = gcc_jit_type_get_pointer(t);
    gcc_jit_type* size_type = gcc_jit_context_get_type(ctx, GCC_JIT_TYPE_SIZE_T);
    gcc_jit_type* byte_type_ptr = gcc_jit_type_get_pointer(gcc_jit_context_get_int_type(ctx, 1, 0));

    gcc_jit_rvalue* one = gcc_jit_context_new_rvalue_from_int(ctx, size_type, 1);

    gcc_jit_rvalue* ptr_0 = gcc_jit_context_new_rvalue_from_ptr(ctx, t_ptr_type, &NULL_PTR);
    gcc_jit_rvalue* ptr_1 = gcc_jit_lvalue_get_address(gcc_jit_context_new_array_access(ctx, NULL, ptr_0, one), NULL);

    ptr_0 = gcc_jit_context_new_cast(ctx, NULL, ptr_0, byte_type_ptr);
    ptr_1 = gcc_jit_context_new_cast(ctx, NULL, ptr_1, byte_type_ptr);

    return gcc_jit_context_new_binary_op(ctx, NULL, GCC_JIT_BINARY_OP_MINUS, size_type, ptr_1, ptr_0);
}
```

EDIT:
I just figured out how to cast a pointer to an integer type as well.  You can bitwise and it with itself and set the result type to a size_t.

```
ptr_0 = gcc_jit_context_new_binary_op(ctx, NULL, GCC_JIT_BINARY_OP_BITWISE_AND, size_type, ptr_0, ptr_0);
ptr_1 = gcc_jit_context_new_binary_op(ctx, NULL, GCC_JIT_BINARY_OP_BITWISE_AND, size_type, ptr_1, ptr_1);

return gcc_jit_context_new_binary_op(ctx, NULL, GCC_JIT_BINARY_OP_MINUS, size_type, ptr_1, ptr_0);
```